# How to delete all txt files inside an FTP directory?

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

My app stores txt files on a FTP server which are also hosted on webservice.

In the directory where I host txt files I can find other txt files. I would like to delete all files in current directory every time when I store the new ones.

Actually i was trying to use the following command:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(siteFTP);
if (ftpClient.login(usrFTP, pswFTP)) {
  ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();          
  FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(path);
  if (remoteFiles.length > 0) {
    ftpClient.deleteFile("/prenotazioni/*.txt");
  }
}
```

But even if there was txt files in that directory, FTP respose is:

```
> DELE /prenotazioni/*.txt
> 550 File not found
```

Comment: What is Your ftpClient variable?  What does it do? Please provide more data so we could help You.

Comment: @deadfish updated the question by adding the exact code i'm using.

Comment: Using `*` won't work. After You get list of files in declared directory, You must iterate it and delete files one by one by using `deleteFile(String pathname)` (also checking if file name endsWith(".txt")). Every FTPFile has method `getName()`. You should construct full path so FTPClient will know what file to delete. I believe it would be something like `ftpClient.deleteFile("/prenotazioni/" + remoteFiles[i].getName());`

Comment: @deadfish that was it, make an answer so i could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `*` won't work. After You get list of files in declared directory, You must iterate it and delete files one by one by using `deleteFile(String pathname)` (also checking if file name `endsWith(".txt")`).

Every `FTPFile` has method `getName()`. You should construct full path so `FTPClient` will know what file to delete. I believe it would be something like:

```
ftpClient.deleteFile("/prenotazioni/" + remoteFiles[i].getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

full method:

```
    public static void deleteFilesInFolderFtp(String dirPath, FTPClient ftpClient) {
    try {
        // use local passive mode to pass firewall
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles("/" + dirPath);
        if (remoteFiles.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < remoteFiles.length; i++) {
                ftpClient.deleteFile("/" + dirPath + "/" + remoteFiles[i].getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```